# Query the MongoDB for the documents whose id-s are contained inside a list

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose you have a list of id-s which can contain up to thousands id-s for the documents inside the database. What is the best way to get those documents back?

Should I invoke a query for each of them or should I specify a giant OR query? may be there is something way better I do not know of

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, $in :

```
db.co.find({_id:{$in:[id1, id2, id3, .., idN]}})
```

Comment: Is it OK to have thousands of values there?

Comment: Yes, there's no practical limit. I believe the query as a whole should not exceed 16Mb but you'll never hit that limit. And even if you do you can batch it.

Comment: The query. It ends up as BSON on the line and that must not exceed 16Mb. The string can be even longer since that's less efficient in terms of size. Either way it's way bigger than you'll ever practically need.

Answer (score 8):

In c# code, [$in](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$in):

```
var ids = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var query = Query.In("name", BsonArray.Create(ids));
var items = collection.Find(query);
```